# Databricks Update - Failures - nondeterministic expressions

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am facing an error while updating a delta table based on a view.
I have already been through various such questions in SO/Google, but none of them seem to provide an actual cause of the issue. Also similar behavior is noticed in DELETE as well. Exists does not seem like a non-deterministic function. So what is triggering the issue ?

Would be nice if someone can please explain what is causing the issue and how it can be resolved.

**Requirement:**

We have an audit table which contains entries with a status flag. We have a global_temp view with just the file names that have been processed. Global temp view is built from a dataframe (`df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("VW_TO_UPD_FILES")`.

We are trying to update the audit table based on this view using the below query.

```sql
UPDATE audit.status S
SET status_flag = 'P'
    ,upd_by = 'test_user'
    --,upd_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT file_name
        FROM GLOBAL_TEMP.VW_TO_UPD_FILES
        WHERE S.file_name = file_name
        )
    AND PROCESS_NAME = 'test_process_name'
    AND SUB_PROCESS_NAME = 'test_sub_process_name'
    AND FOLDER_DATE = '2024-02-04'
    AND status_flag = 'N'
```

**Error Message:**

`AnalysisException: nondeterministic expressions are only allowed in Project, Filter, Aggregate or Window, found:`

**Tried Options:**

None of the below options work.

- Have commented out the current_timestamp().
- Have tried bringing the additional filters within exists itself.
- Have tried aliasing the view and the other columns as well.

**WorkArounds Known:**

As of now, we are proceeding with a merge statement which seems to be working, but would like to know why an update similar to the one available in Databricks Website does not work. Refer [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/delta-update#examples).

**Env:**

Databricks Runtime 12.2

Spark 3.3.2

Python/PySpark Code.

Comment: spark.sql("""
    UPDATE audit.status S
    SET status_flag = 'P',
        upd_by = 'test_user'
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT file_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS cur_timestamp
        FROM global_temp.VW_TO_UPD_FILES
        WHERE S.file_name = file_name
    )
    AND PROCESS_NAME = 'test_process_name'
    AND SUB_PROCESS_NAME = 'test_sub_process_name'
    AND FOLDER_DATE = '2024-02-04'
    AND status_flag = 'N'
""")
@rainingdistros
Can you try the above and let me know if you are able to update the audit table

Comment: Still the same error...in fact - I removed the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() column from the entire query - even with just the status_flag and upd_by, it is still failing...

Comment: I tried this at my end spark.sql("""
    UPDATE audit.status S
    SET status_flag = 'P',
        upd_by = 'test_user',
        upd_at = current_timestamp()
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT file_name
        FROM global_temp.VW_TO_UPD_FILES
        WHERE S.file_name = file_name
    ) AND PROCESS_NAME = 'test_process_name'
    AND SUB_PROCESS_NAME = 'test_sub_process_name'
    AND FOLDER_DATE = '2024-02-04'
    AND status_flag = 'N'
""")

It worked for me

Comment: let me know if it worked for you

Comment: this is essentially the same query as what I had mentioned in the question right ? It is not working...